# Linux Resolution set wrong

Tags: ubuntu, resolution

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running. It was working fine until I tried to load Windows onto a partition. I had to quit because I needed to format one of my drives which I had some important files on. When I switched back to ubuntu, my screen resolution was set to 4:3 instead of 16:9 and when I clicked 'display' I could not set it back, as 4:3 was the only option available. How do I revert back to 16:9?

Also, when I run `sudo xrandr -q`, I get the following error:

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to add the resolution mode, you can check it here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/712564/why-cant-i-see-169-aspect-ratios

or here if that doesn't works:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/

Comment: None of these solutions work because every time I run the xrandr command, I get the same error as before.